# Red shift of radio signals

Tags: special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, radio-frequency, redshift

If a radio signal is red-shifted does it still last the same amount of time?
Knowing the signal wavelength is now longer but still is traveling at the speed of light one would assume the radio message would have consequently slowed down.
I tried to search for an answer but found none.
I do not know how I could set up an experiment to confirm or disprove this.

Comment: *"If a radio signal is red-shifted does it still last the same amount of time?"* - For simplicity, stipulate the radio signal is [On-off keying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-off_keying) (think Morse code over radio). Are you asking if the red-shifted 'dits' and 'dahs' last longer than they were originally keyed?

Comment: Let $N$ be the number of wavecrests received. If the time between successive received wavecrests (according to the receiver) is $\kappa$ times longer than the time between those same transmitted wavecrests (according to the transmitted), then the overall duration of the received signal must be $\kappa$ times longer than the duration of the transmitted signal. No experiment is required; just add up the times between all the successive wavecrests to get the total duration (received or transmitted).